# How to tile background image right to left

Tags: html, css

I have the following background image: [image]

I want to use this as a background for a div, but to be placed at the bottom of the div and only to tile left to right, and not top to bottom. In addition, I want the background colour to the div to be `#e4e5e6`, so the colour shows through where the transparent blocks are.

Here is my start:

HTML

```
<div class="tiles"></div>
```

CSS

```
 .tiles {
   width:100%;
   height:400px;
   background-color: #e4e5e6;
   background: url('tiles-bg.png') bottom left fixed ;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
 }
```

However, this approach centers the image in the center and still tiles top to bottom. It also fails to show the background color.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all background related properties into one declaration, like this:

```
.tiles {   
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   background: #e4e5e6  url('tiles-bg.png') bottom left repeat-x;
 }
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBLGV/)

Answer (score 0):

for background propities, you should use somthing like this:

```
background: #e4e5e6 url('tiles-bg.png') bottom left fixed repeat-x;
```

You see, propeties "background" - is general, and when you use background-color, then after background, you turn off the property for background-color.